# Using the COV function in Pig

Tags: apache-pig, covariance, built-in

For some reason, I am not able to get a grasp of the proper syntax for this function.

I have a file called testing.txt:

```
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
```

I have a Pig script:

```
 testing = load '/testing.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (var1:double);

 t = foreach testing generate var1, var1 as var2;

 grp = group t all;

 result = foreach grp generate AVG(t.var1) as average, COV(t.var1,t.var2) as variance;

 dump result;
```

This should give me the mean and variance.

I tried this as well:

```
testing = load '/testing.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (var1:double);

grp = group t all;

result = foreach grp generate AVG(testing.var1) as average, COV(testing.var1,testing.var1) as variance;

dump result;
```

Both these scripts give me the same error:

```
ERROR 2078: Caught error from UDF: org.apache.pig.builtin.COV$Intermed [Caught exception in COV.Intermed]
```

I looked in the [Java code](https://github.com/apache/pig/blob/branch-0.13/src/org/apache/pig/builtin/COV.java) and couldn't find anything out of the ordinary.

I was wondering how to use function COV in Pig.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve. Do you want to compute variance of all the numbers ([1-8] in example) in data? All the values need to passed to COV function to get their variance.
COV(1,1) will return 0 (which you are trying to do).
COV(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) will give you the actual variance of all the data.
Hope this helps!

Comment: In oreder to compute Covariance you need atleast two variables in tuple (you cant pass the same variable twice) can you try http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/1.1.0/datafu/pig/stats/VAR.html also check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance on what covariance is.

Comment: I know what the covariance is. I am trying to find the variance of my data. The only way to do this using the built in functions in Pig is by using the COV function. The problem is that I am not clear on how the inputs should be formatted. Should I create a tuple and then pass it into the function?

Comment: Gaurav, COV(t.var1,t.var2) should apply the function on the entire column in Pig, not just the first row.

Comment: Any news on this? I need to use cov too :\